# Lifetime error for returned value of a function

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is a simplified version of a piece of code I am trying to implement:

```rust
struct FirstStruct
{
    a:  i8,
}

impl FirstStruct
{
     fn get(&self) -> Option<&str>
     {
         Some("aaa")
     }
}

pub struct SecondStruct<'a>
{
    pub name:           Option<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> SecondStruct<'a>
{
    fn extract_string(obj: &/*'a*/ FirstStruct) -> Option<&'a str>
    {
        obj.get() //this is where the error happen
    }

    pub fn from_string() -> SecondStruct<'a>
    {
        let obj = FirstStruct{a: 1};
        SecondStruct{
            name:       SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj),
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let g_def_res = SecondStruct::from_string();
}
```

This code throws the following error :

```
test2.rs:23:13: 23:18 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
test2.rs:23         obj.get() //this is where the error happen
                        ^~~~~
test2.rs:21:5: 24:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn extract_string(obj: &'a FirstStruct) -> Option<&'a str>
test2.rs:21     fn extract_string(obj: &FirstStruct) -> Option<&'a str>
test2.rs:22     {
test2.rs:23         obj.get() //this is where the error happen
test2.rs:24     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Applying the proposed solution throw this error :

```
test2.rs:30:55: 30:58 error: `obj` does not live long enough
test2.rs:30             name:       SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj),
                                                                  ^~~
test2.rs:27:5: 32:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 27:4...
test2.rs:27     {
test2.rs:28         let obj = FirstStruct{a: 1};
test2.rs:29         SecondStruct{
test2.rs:30             name:       SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj),
test2.rs:31         }
test2.rs:32     }
test2.rs:28:37: 32:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 28:36
test2.rs:28         let obj = FirstStruct{a: 1};
test2.rs:29         SecondStruct{
test2.rs:30             name:       SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj),
test2.rs:31         }
test2.rs:32     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

To summarise:

How to say that the return value of `FirstStruct::get` must have the lifetime of either [the return value of `SecondStruct::from_str` | the struct lifetime `'a`]? I think both refer to same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
pub fn from_string() -> SecondStruct<'a> {
    let obj = FirstStruct { a: 1 };
    SecondStruct {
        name: SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj),
    }
}
```

This code says "I will return a `SecondStruct` with the lifetime `'a`". The **caller** of the code gets to determine what the length of the lifetime `'a` is. This is almost never what you want!

```
// Lifetime elision means the method is equivalent to this
// fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a str>

fn get(&self) -> Option<&str> {
    Some("aaa")
}
```

This code uses says that the string returned will live as long as `self` lives.

Put these two concepts together, and you can understand your error. The variable `obj` is only defined to live as long as the function call is active. However, you are trying to return a reference to the inner-workings of the struct beyond the call! Actually, you are trying to return it for *any arbitrary lifetime* the caller decides! This is Rust preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot, hooray for Rust!

---

So how do you fix your problem? For the provided example code, the easiest thing is to just use the `'static` lifetime:

```rust
struct FirstStruct { a: i8 }

impl FirstStruct {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&'static str> { Some("aaa") }
}

pub struct SecondStruct<'a> { name: Option<&'a str> }

impl<'a> SecondStruct<'a> {
    fn extract_string(obj: &FirstStruct) -> Option<&'static str> { obj.get() }

    pub fn from_string() -> SecondStruct<'static> {
        let obj = FirstStruct { a: 1 };
        SecondStruct { name: SecondStruct::extract_string(&obj) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let g_def_res = SecondStruct::from_string();
}
```

But that's probably not what you really want. The next thing to try would be to *embed* `FirstStruct` inside `SecondStruct`, and simply delegate to it. Another option would be to move from `&str` to `String` - `String` owns the string data, and so you can transfer ownership from `First` to `Second`.

Whatever you do, you have to ensure that the source of the string data outlives the function call to `from_string`.

---

> Either the return value of `FirstStruct::get` has been allocated on the stack or it has been allocated on the heap.

It's trickier than that. The return value is *always* on the stack. That is, the `Option<&str>` takes up space on the stack. The `&str` may contain a pointer to something that is allocated either on the stack or heap, it's not known by this code. All you know is that the pointed-at value is guaranteed to live for the lifetime of that specific `FirstStruct` item.

You don't own the string, so you can't transfer ownership around.

> I can't move FirstStruct because it is from another library (rustc-serialize

I'm not sure what you mean. If you have an object, then you can embed it into your object. The fact that it comes from another crate doesn't come into play. If you have a reference to something, then you can still capture the reference, but then your object has to live for a shorter period than the reference (so that it never becomes invalid).

> Unwrapping Option, updating to a string and rewrapping in Option is a lot of boilerplate.

Have you seen `Option::map`? It makes this kind of thing very succinct. Combined with `From`, you can write a very short thing to convert an `Option<&str>` to `Option<String>`:

```
// fn is just to establish some types, you'd just use the `.map` call in real code
fn foo(a: Option<&str>) -> Option<String> {
    a.map(From::from)
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand : Either #1 the return value of FirstStruct::get() has been allocated on the stack and then it shouldn't have been returned or #2 the return value of FirstStruct::get() has been allocated on the heap and then there must be a way to say : "Don't deallocate it, I transfer the return value from FirstStruct to SecondStruct associating it with SecondStruct's lifetime". Isn't it ?

Comment: #1 as you expect, I don't want to use static #2 I can't move FirstStruct because it is from another library (rustc-serialize) #3 I already tried this solution and it work, but this is boilerplate (unwraping Option, update to string and rewrap in Option) #4 Thanks a lot for taking time to answer and edit my post. Rust community is definitely awesome.

Comment: @Moebius I've updated with some more details. If that still doesn't help, then perhaps someone else will be able to provide a more clear answer!